# OpenGL GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH same as N64 Hardware anti-aliasing?

Tags: opengl, graphics, filtering, antialiasing, nintendo

Here is an explanation of how anti-aliasing was performed on the Nintendo 64 hardware: http://n64devkit.square7.ch/tutorial/graphics/6/6_1.htm

Am I correct that this is more or less the same way as the somewhat outdated (and badly supported) GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH with glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL_ONE) based anti-aliasing is (supposed to be) working?

If not, what are the key differences? In particular, are there different requirements for rendering order?